# How to setup OVH firewall for OpenVPN server?

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, openvpn, ovh

I got my OpenVPN server running, by using this script: https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install

I can connect to VPN network, ping local and external IP addresses, access HTTP server (by using local and external IP).

DNS is not working on clients, when I try pinging google.com/any-other-domain it displays IP resolve error.
When I try nslookup on all domains, it retries few times and returns dns timeout.

- My external IP: 147.135.XXX.XXX
- My VPN network: 10.8.0.0/24
- My internal IP: 10.8.0.1

I tried

- Default and non default VPN server port
- TCP and UDP
- Adguard, Google, and local hosted DNS server (on VPN)
- Opening port 53 UDP on VPN server

None worked so far.

Then I disabled OVH firewall. After that, DNS stared working on VPN clients.

So, how should I configure OVH firewall?
I don't want to disable it completely, because I'm hosting many other things on that server.

I know, that rules are applied from the lowest priority to highest.
So if rule 0 is matched, then rules 1-19 are not executed.

My current configuration:
[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLt10.png)

Hidden ports are set up exactly like 80 and 443. Established TCP connections are accepted, connections on specific ports are accepted and TCP/UDP on 1194 is also accepted.

Thanks for help.
Also, please post comment, if I missed something.

Comment: Have you tried creating a rule to allow DNS queries to pass through ? Ie. allow UDP from your clients to outside with a target port set to 53

Comment: @NaeiKinDus Thanks for comment. I opened port 53 UDP on VPN server and this solution didn't fix the problem. New rule: _[Protocol: UDP, Source IP: Any, Source port: Any, Target port: 53]_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit late but I answer.
For my openvpn server to forward properly I had to open UDP **SOURCE** port 53.

So, the rule is not:

- [Protocol: UDP, Source IP: Any, Source port: Any, Target port: 53],

but:

- [Protocol: UDP, Source IP: Any, Source port: 53, Target port: any].

Comment: I am not familiar with OVH firewall, but by the looks of it it probably needs a _pair_ of rules -- one to allow the local machine to query any remote DNS server ( "allow remote UDP port 53" ) and one more for replies to pass through the firewall ( "allow return UDP packets _from_ port 53" ) .

To add, one may want to do the same for _TCP_ port 53, since longer DNS queries may use the TCP protocol instead of UDP .

Comment: I'll keep in mind if something does not work.

Comment: It started working after adding: [Protocol: UDP, Source IP: any, Source port: any, Target port: 53]
[Protocol: UDP, Source IP: any, Source port: 53, Target port: any]
[Protocol: TCP, Source IP: any, Source port: 53, Target port: any]

Comment: Anyway, I won't apply these rules to production, because I don't think, that allowing TCP traffic to _any_ port is safe. Also, I updated my project to not use any DNS at all.

Comment: Very strange thing, I didn't need to open all tcp ports. I just made a private transparent vpn for myself on ovh vps and just opened UDP source port 53 to have forwarding working. VPS is configured to forward properly.